# Linear Algebra Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Determining the values of a for which the Matrix A has an inverse !

A=   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & 1  \\ 2 & a+2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & a \end{pmatrix}

How i solved it:

```
x1  + ax2     + x3  = y1
2x1 + (a+2)x2 + x3  =    y2
x1  + 2x2     + ax3 =      y3
```

Idont know if this is correct and i dont know what to do next?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is calculate the determinant. Find out for which values of $a$, $\det\text A\ne 0$.

Comment: If you've already covered determinants, you could see when the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: @user84413 how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want that the only solution to the following is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & a & 1 \\ 2 & a+2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & a\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$$

is the zero solution (i.e. $0 = x_1 = x_2 = x_3$). This says that $A$ is invertible. Rewriting this as an augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & a+2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & a & 0\end{array}\right]$$

Row reducing ($R_2\to R_2-2R_1$ and $R_3\to R_3-R_1$), we get

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-a & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-a & a-1 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

Another row reduction ($R_3\to R_3-R_2$) gives

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-a & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a & 0\end{array}\right]$$

Since this is in upper triangular form, the only way for the solution to be trivial (meaning $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$) is if the pivots are nonzero (otherwise the matrix is not invertible). Can you take it from here?

Comment: How to do that?? full solution plz?

Comment: @user2393690 Have you done determinants in your class yet?

Comment: Not yet, anyway i googled how to do it and i got -a^2 +2a  is this correct?

Comment: Yes but I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok we got -a^2+2a and what next?

Comment: @user2393690 Now set the determinant equal to 0 and solve for a; these are the values for which the matrix is NOT invertible.

Comment: its will be a= +-sqrt(2) ? @user84413

Comment: I've edited my post so that you can use techniques already available to you.

Comment: @user2393690 This gives $a(2-a)=0$, so $a=0$ and $a=2$ are the only values of a for which the matrix is NOT invertible. (See Cameron Williams' solution for a way to do this without determinants.)

Comment: Thank you @CameronWilliams and @ user84413 for the help, so the a in last row give is equal to 0 and in the second and first row is  equal to 2 ?

Comment: @user2393690 Exactly. Those are the values for which $A$ **is not** invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is not equal to zero.

You can use Gaussian elimination to find the values of $a$ that will make $A$ invertible, that is, those values of $a$ such that $\det A\ne 0$. You can easily verify that you can reduce $A$ to the form

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & 1\\
0 & 2-a & -1 \\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

in a few easy steps with Gaussian elimination. Check it!

This reduced matrix and the original one have the same determinant. Moreover, the determinant of the reduced matrix equals the product of its diagonal entries. Therefore, we conclude that 
$$
\det A=(2-a)a.
$$

So $A$ is invertible if and only if $a\ne 0,2$.